# Rails field select box with icons only

Tags: jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

I want to display a field selectbox which is basically color with only icons of color images without any caption for the options. What is the best way to achieve that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for this? http://jsfiddle.net/yLdu7/1/

```
  <select style="width: 100px">
    <option style="background: #3C81F3" value="blue"></option>
    <option style="background: #88B541" value="green"></option>
    <option style="background: #EE9702" value="orange"></option>
    <option style="background: #FAD160" value="brown"></option>
  </select>
```

I know it's a silly stuff.

**Updated**

Just put a simple script:

```
$("#select-box").change(function(){
   var col = $(this).val();
   //alert(col);
    $(this).css('backgroundColor',col);
});
```

Check it out in fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yLdu7/1/

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, This works fine until, I select something. The selected color does not stay selected although the correct value is passed.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to use a framework. Standard select boxes don't support image selections.

Here is one of my favorites for this functionality:

http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/

It supports a bunch of different features for select fields and plays nice with standard text fields.

Comment: How to use it with the rails form fields ?

Comment: Check out this video tutorial: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/using-select2-with-ruby-on-rails-treehouse-quick-tip